# Alternatives to traditional algorithms for encoding UUIDS (e.g. Base32, Base62)

Tags: algorithm, guid, uuid

We need to convert huge numbers of UUIDS into xml-compatible strings. If we use a Base32 algorithm (which maps each 5 bits to one of 32 characters) this leads to 26 char strings, if we us a Base62 algorithm (which iteratively divides the 128 bit integer by 62 and records the modulus as one of 62 characters) this leads to 22 char strings. While base62 returns shorter strings it is much more cpu-intensive, therefore we are stuck with Base32 (Base64 is not an option because of xml).

Do you know any other types of encoding algorithms that could help us here? Are there variants of Base32-like bit pattern encoding algorithms that could be used with bases that are not powers of 2? Or are there hybrid algorithms which combine approaches of the first with approaches of the second algorithm? We would like to reduce the char strings to less than 26 if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned 62, which suggests that you are limiting your alphabet to A-Z (capitalised and lowercase) and the digits 0-9.  Why not add another couple of XML compatible characters to that list, such as `+`, `.`, `~` or `!` to bring that number up to 64?  You'll be be able to do bit-shifting rather than division, which should make the algorithm as fast as the Base32 one and reduce your string sizes.

**Edit:** Since the restriction that these characters are also available for other *as yet unspecified* languages, you might care to escape some of your characters to represent your 64 options.  If you use, for example, _ as an escape character you could have _1 and _2 represent options 63 and 64.  The statistics mention in the original question suggest that UUIDS are 128-bits, so our Base64 would give us 22 characters if there is no escaping and, where up to 4 items are escaped, keeps within your 26 characters.

Comment: Good point, thank you! But XML is not the only restriction for us, we also need to use it for generating class names in some programming languages (where the underscore would be another character but I haven't been able to find a 64th usable ASCII character).

Comment: @Carina - I've added a suggestion, re escaping, which might assist if you've run out of characters.  You'd be best off - if you can - finding your extra 64th character.

Comment: You've probably already thought of this, but also realize that most languages don't allow class names to start with a number. So you should probably prefix all of these with some legal character as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia offers two versions of Base64 that are usable in XML namespaces.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#XML. I wrote the following JAVA that follows to do URLSafe, UUIDs in Java, (call theObjectReturned.toString() to get it as a guid string).

I've seen other code for Java that is supposed to be very fast and could be easily modified to do the XML safe variants:

http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/

code follows. Save in a file called UUIDUtil.java

```
public class UUIDUtil{
public static UUID combUUID(){
    private UUID srcUUID = UUID.randomUUID();;
    private java.sql.Timestamp ts = new java.sql.Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());

    long upper16OfLowerUUID = this.zeroLower48BitsOfLong( srcUUID.getLeastSignificantBits() );
    long lower48Time = UUIDUtil.zeroUpper16BitsOfLong( ts );
    long lowerLongForNewUUID = upper16OfLowerUUID | lower48Time;
    return new UUID( srcUUID.getMostSignificantBits(), lowerLongForNewUUID );
}   
public static base64URLSafeOfUUIDObject( UUID uuid ){
    byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(16).putLong(0, uuid.getLeastSignificantBits()).putLong(8, uuid.getMostSignificantBits()).array();
    return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString( bytes );
}
public static base64URLSafeOfUUIDString( String uuidString ){
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString( uuidString );
    return UUIDUtil.base64URLSafeOfUUIDObject( uuid );
}
private static long zeroLower48BitsOfLong( long longVar ){
    long upper16BitMask =  -281474976710656L;
    return longVar & upper16BitMask;
}
private static void zeroUpper16BitsOfLong( long longVar ){
    long lower48BitMask =  281474976710656L-1L;
    return longVar & lower48BitMask;
}
```

}

Comment: Very interesting. But problem with the approaches you mention in XML is that element names may not begin with a digit and may not start with 'xml'or 'XML'. Both the Wikipedia article's approach and the base64URLSafeOfUUIDObject will lead to some encodings that dont match those requirements.

Comment: I would not even have thought of using the output of a UUID generator for the name of element, only the datum in an element. Can you give me an example of doing that? Just to satisfy my curiosity and ingnorance? :-)